# how to run recursively "touch empty" if a folder is empty?

Tags: command-line

I want to maintain a folder structure that contains empty folders when I add a project to Git. As everyone knows, Git doesn't track empty folders. So you need to add some kind of placeholder inside of an empty folder.

So far I have managed to find out recursively empty folders with this command:

```
find ./* -type d -empty
```

How do I continue? So after a command every empty folder contains a file called "empty"?

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -type d -empty -exec touch {}/empty \;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I tried both this and what Ignacio wrote, and this one works. The other one uses the -execdir option, which always runs the command at the directory containing the file. Since the "file" is an empty directory, it runs `touch empty` at the directory **containing** the empty directory, not the empty directory itself. Rick got it right in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Run `touch empty` in the directory.

```
find ... -execdir touch empty \;
```

Comment: That one above only added empty on "." (current) folder. I'm running this on Linux if that helps...? I ran across to a blog post which claimed that there are some differences between MacOSX and Linux. Here: http://aplawrence.com/Unixart/find_execdir.html

Comment: Are you running the command exactly as Ignacio wrote? I think he means for you to run `find . -type d -empty -execdir touch empty \;`

Comment: thanks for clarification. I was doing it wrong, but still it won't add that empty file to all folders... actually it adds it only in "."-folder and "./level1/"-folder, which is btw not empty. This is strange,    find . -type d -empty    displays all correct folders though..

Comment: I've just tested it, and I'm getting the same behaviour... bizarrely, it *seems* to be touching the 'empty' files in the directory one above the empty directories.

Answer (score 0):

Mandatory 'you can do this with bash' answer:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for f in ./**/; do [[ $(echo "$f"*) == '' ]] && touch "$f"empty; done
```

Globstar means that `**` expands into 'every file in this directory, recursively'; `**/` means that it will only expand to directories, rather than regular files (since filenames can't contain forward-slashes).

Nullglob means that globs which don't match anything expand to a nullbyte. The test checks if this happens (which would mean that there's nothing in the directory); if the test evaluates to true (which means there's nothing in the directory), then it `touch`es `empty` in the directory.